# No more audio through HDMI in 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: sound, 22.04

Ok, I've been running Ubuntu 22.04 for a while now. Everything worked fine until an update a few months ago.

Now, when I am connect and HDMI cable to my laptop, the audio will *always* use the internal speakers.

Under settings / Sound, I see the HDMI output device. If select it, and use the "test" feature, then the sound comes out of the "built-in" speakers (instead of the HDMI) and moving the volume control has no effect.

Selecting "build-in speakers" works as expected.

I think this is the audio controller:

```
0000:00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 189, IOMMU group 14
    Memory at 601f270000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 601f000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
```

I am not sure what to try to get the audio "routing" to work correctly.

additional:

- 3.5mm Headphones work fine (sound is routed to headphones)
- using bluetooth headphones, the sound is still routed to the "buildin speakers" vs the bluetooth ones.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The audio chipset has nothing to do with Bluetooth audio. The relevant question is: Are you selecting the Bluetooth audio output and the sound still being routed to the internal speakers? If so you have a problem indeed.

Comment: @ChanganAuto... that's exactly it. Audio is always routed to the internal speakers

Comment: Note. If I plug in headphones and then unplug them, I can get sound to route through the HDMI port.